# Doxygen: hiding part of source code in source code browser

Tags: c, hide, doxygen

1. Generally I want Doxygen to allow viewing the source code of documented files. But I want a **part of the source code to be hidden**.
   I know how to force Doxygen not to document certain piece of code (e.g. with /cond /endcond), but it still appears when clicking on "Go to the source code of this file".

   What I actually want is: if something is not commented in Doxygen-style, it shall appear nowhere at all, not in the documentation nor within "Go to the source code of this file".
   This shall be the case for functions as well as for #-defines or whatever.
2. I use @hideinitializer to hide the initializer for #-defines. That works well within the documentation. But again, the initializer is still shown within the source code.

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pre-process source files by specifying a filter script/program using the [`INPUT_FILTER`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_input_filter) option. Then, by setting [`FILTER_SOURCE_FILE = YES`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_filter_source_files), the filtered source code will be used in the source browser rather than the original source.

From the docs:

> The INPUT_FILTER tag can be used to specify a program that doxygen should invoke to filter for each input file. Doxygen will invoke the filter program by executing (via popen()) the command:
>
> `<filter> <input-file>`
>
> where  is the value of the INPUT_FILTER tag, and  is the name of an input file. Doxygen will then use the output that the filter program writes to standard output.

and

> If the FILTER_SOURCE_FILES tag is set to YES, the input filter (if set using INPUT_FILTER ) will also be used to filter the input files that are used for producing the source files to browse (i.e. when SOURCE_BROWSER is set to YES).

---

As a crude example, using the following source (saved as `filter.py` in the same location as Doxyfile, and made executable):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import fileinput, re

# output all lines that does not start with // (but allow //!)
for line in fileinput.input():
  if not re.match(r'\s*//(?![!])', line):
    print line,
```

and in Doxyfile, setting:

```
INPUT_FILTER = ./filter.py
FILTER_SOURCE_FILE = YES
```

The output source browser will now show only lines that do not start with `//`.

Naturally, creating a filter script that discards all C-style comments except those that are relevant to doxygen will be a lot more involved than the one shown above.